# How to bind/pass varibles in Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to pass variable in to Spark data frame filter and for IF condition.

I am populates value from Spark dataframe

```
val data=sqlContext.sql("Select Col from Tables1")
```

I want to pass this variable data into dataframe filter option.

I tried the below one but it is give empty value.

```
val df=df1.filter($"Column1"===data) and
val df=df1.filter($"Column1"===$data)
```

Both are not working.

And I tried to use in IF statement.

```
if $data="String" -- How to pass in IF .
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Following expression can be used:

```
df1.filter($"Column1=$data")
```

for strings quotes is required:

```
df1.filter($"Column1='$data'")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you try to filter a dataframe.
You can do it like this :

```
val df = sqlContext.sql("Select Col from Tables1")
df.filter(df("Col") === "100")
```

Here you filter your data keeping only lines with Col = "100".
But "100" is a constant.
Apparently you want to filter with values coming from another dataframe.

You have to use a `join` for this.

```
val data = sqlContext.sql("Select Col from Data")
val df1 = sqlContext.sql("Select id, Col from Table1")
val df = df1.join(data, df1("Col") === data("Col"))
```